# Using jQuery to retrieve JSON via AJAX

Tags: jquery, json

This is a basic example from Microsoft Virtual Academy course.
I don't know why, but I can't get data from json file.
Every time I click "Get JSON Data" I see alert `There was a problem with the server. Try again soon!`
Do I need something special to get access to the json file or the code is wrong?
I'm running this test-site using Microsoft WebMatrix. But from what I know, the json should work the same way as javascript or html, I mean "without server".

Please, let me know what should I do to understand why this code doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#clickme').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'data19.json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          var items = [];

          $.each(data, function(key, val) {

            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');    

          });

          $('<ul/>', {
             'class': 'interest-list',
             html: items.join('')
          }).appendTo('body');

       },
      statusCode: {
         404: function() {
           alert('There was a problem with the server.  Try again soon!');
         }
       }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>JavaScript Example</title>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script19.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
 <h1 id="title">19. Using jQuery to retrieve JSON via AJAX</h1>
 
 <a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON Data</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**The content of data19.json file**

```
{
    "one": "Learned Optimism",
    "two": "Deliberate Practice",
    "three": "Getting Things Done"
}
```

edit:
**All files are next to each other in one folder.**
index.html
script19.js
data19.json

edit 13.01.2016:
**The following code works.**
The problem was web serwer configuration - IIS Express (Microsoft Webmatrix). AJAX needs to use **CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**. I still cannot configure IIS Express correctly, to get access to the json file but I've tested this code using provider's hosting.

Comment: From where do you getting this JSON file ?

Comment: @Frebin All files are on the same level, in one folder. I've made a test with simpler code and now I see clearly, the file is not found. I don't know why. `$.getJSON('data19.json', function (data) {
 console.log('It worked');
});` 
The error message _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)_

Comment: *But from what I know, the json should work the same way as javascript or html, I mean "without server".* — You're wrong. XMLHttpRequest is subject to security restrictions about accessing local files. Since it you are getting a 404 error though … it sounds like you DO have a server and your URL is just wrong.

Comment: I've watched this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-S5MBs4y0Q tutorial and I made everything right. **I've tested this script with Webmatrix turned on and off.** I'm sure the path to the file is correct. I've made some examples and none of them doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put all your js file in one folder like js/. or for current scenario put your data19.json file where your script19.js present. this will run code successfully

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h1 id="title">19. Using jQuery to retrieve JSON via AJAX</h1>

<button id="clickme">Get JSON Data</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('button').on('click', function() {
        alert('on click');
       $.ajax({
           url: 'data.json',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
              var items = [];
              alert('abc');

              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');    
              });

              $('<ul/>', {
                 'class': 'interest-list',
                 html: items.join('')
              }).appendTo('body');

           },
          error: function() {
               alert('There was a problem with the server.  Try again soon!');
             }
        });
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: But all files are in one folder on the same level, next to the index.html and script19.js

Comment: I've made a new, simpler version of code and now I see that, the json file is not found. I don't know why because I've checked the name and I'm sure it's on the same level as other files. Here's the new code `$.getJSON('data19.json', function (data) { console.log('It worked'); });` and the error message is: _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)_
I've tested it in Firefox and Chrome, in both the same 404 error. I made everything the same like in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/j-S5MBs4y0Q?t=209) this time and opposed to the author I get 404 error.

Comment: error should be "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/mm/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." now try to run your same html on firefox it will work fine. because chrome not allow cross origin request, You must have some server to run same on chrome

Comment: I'm using Microsoft WebMatrix (IIS Express) and I was testing this code using FIrefox and Chrome. In both is the same 404 error (Not found).

Comment: Your code doesn't work. I see "on click" alert and then "There was a problem..". In console I see this _GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:27057/data.json [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:27057/data.json [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]_ **I've changed the name of the json file to "data.json"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100457/discussion-between-rafr3-and-shree29).

Answer (score 0):

404 means the URL is not found. Try placing the 'data19.json' file in the same folder as the script file.

Comment: All files are on the same level, in one folder. I've made a test with simpler code and now I see clearly, the file is not found. I don't know why. `$.getJSON('data19.json', function (data) { console.log('It worked'); });` The error message _Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)_

Answer (score -1):

On my attempt to debug your code - click function attached to the $('#clickme') selector is not getting triggered. 
Also, please check the path to "script19.js" - this file is throwing 404 error on console.